# CDF of distance to a point in 3D-sphere

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say we have a unit sphere and want to generate uniformly distributed points inside it. We use rejection to do so, and as such we place the sphere inside a $2$x$2$x$2$ bounding box and generate points uniformly inside of there, rejecting any points that don't end up inside the sphere.

If I'm correct then there is a .23 rejection rate.

But let's say we introduce a random variable $L$ that is the distance from the center of the sphere to a random point inside the sphere. What would the CDF of $L$ be?

Comment: Think about what the CDF $F(r)$ represents.  It is the probability that a random point is closer than some radius $r$.  When is a point closer than some radius $r$?  It is when the point falls within a *sphere* of radius $r$ (centered at the origin); the points within this sphere are all closer to the origin than $r$.  Since the point is selected uniformly from the unit sphere, the probability must be equal to the volume of the smaller sphere, divided by the volume of the unit sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the volume of a sphere of radius $L$ is $\frac{4}{3} \pi L^3$.

Comment: So the CDF is the volume of a sphere with radius 1? I.e the CDF is $\frac{4}{3} \pi$?

Comment: No, the CDF of the distance from the centre of a sphere of radius $R$ to a random point in the sphere is $F(x) = $(volume of sphere of radius $x$)/(volume of sphere of radius $R$) $=x^3/R^3$ for $0 \le x \le R$, $0$ for $x < 0$, $1$ for $x > R$.